# ReactNative ipa get crashed after Splash screen

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, build, react-native-ios

I am new to ReactNative , I have created project with ReactNative and it is running on simulator also on device if device is attached via USB (Android and iOS).

But now I need to send it to the client so I have followed following steps and create ipa it get installed on the device but get close after Splash screen. Please help any help would be appreciated.

Here is the steps that I followed:

1.Executed command on terminal
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios

2.commented this line in AppDelegate.m :

jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];];
and added this one :

jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

But it didn't help then I followed :

1. Opened info.plist and expand the App Transport Security settings and Exception Domains. Under there you’ll find the localhost entry and removed.

2.Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme in xCode. Select Run tab and set the Build Configuration dropdown to Release.

Then Product --> Archive and exported the ipa, But nothing worked for me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you added proper provisioning profile and certificate? Please check it once again?

Comment: @ Ashok Londhe 1  I am using automatic certificate signing

Comment: I think you have to create certificates from developer account and then store it into keychain then you need to select provisioning profile in Xcode and set proper certificate

Comment: @ Ashok Londhe 1  if the app is not signed using proper provisioning profile  and cerificate It would not get install on the device.

Comment: I think then its problem ... please go to setting in iPhone there is option --> General --> Profiles & Device Management ---> Selecte provisioning profile ---> Select your app --> click on trust option

Comment: okey let me try this

Comment: Okay and let me know what happens?

Comment: @ Ashok Londhe no nothing change same result

Comment: share hour skype id i will check what is the problem

Comment: its arnav.malhotra9

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem the error was I was using ScrollView and in React-Native 0.51.0 there is some issue with ScrollView I degrade the version of React-native to 0.49.0 and it solved the problem and to do that I ran the command on terminal:
npm install --save react-native@0.49.0